# Need a good tutorial for programming views in Xcode without interface builder

Tags: xcode, uibutton

I'm currently taking a class on programming the iPhone, and I am struggling with a couple of programs that involve drawing or placing things on the screen and moving them around. I don't want to use interface builder to help me with these, but would rather do that actual coding for it. Does anyone know of a good website that can show how to, say, create and place UIButtons and UITextViews on the screen without the use of interface builder? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through this tutorial.  It talks about both IB and creating views programmatically.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Being able to build the UI programatically, even if you never use it, is a good skill to have. It helps you understand what IB does and makes it easier to modify your UI at runtime. Apple's [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) contains everything you want to know about views, windows, drawing, and the view hierarchy. Also check out the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).